# Multi User Computer Using SharePoint Sync

Tags: sharepoint-online, sync, onedrive

We have a shared computer in the field that has 10 active users. Are there any implication to each of these users syncing the same SharePoint Document Library under their account? Besides HDD space considerations, will there be sync issues between all of these accounts? Is there a better way to do it then individually syncing the same Doc Lib with 10 different accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Windows 10, you'll have Files on Demand so only files which are interacted with will be downloaded to the local drive.

If each user is logging into the machine with their own credentials, there shouldn't be any issue with the scenario you describe.